# merge tables in R, combine cells if in both

Tags: r, merge

Hi can you please explain how I can merge two tables that they can be used to generate a piechart?

```
#read input data
dat = read.csv("/ramdisk/input.csv", header = TRUE, sep="\t")

# pick needed columns and count the occurences of each entry
df1 = table(dat[["C1"]])
df2 = table(dat[["C2"]])

# rename columns
names(df1) <- c("ID", "a", "b", "c", "d")
names(df2) <- c("ID", "e", "f", "g", "h")

# show data for testing purpose
df1  
# ID   a   b   c   d 
#241  18  17  28  29 
df2
# ID   e   f   g   h 
#230  44   8  37  14 
# looks fine so far, now the problem:

# what I want to do ist merging df and df2 
# so that df will contain the overall numbers of each entry
# df should print
# ID   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h 
#471  18  17  28  29   44   8  37  14 
# need them to make a nice piechart in the end
#pie(df)
```

I assume it can be done with merge somehow, but I haven't found the right way. The closest solution I found was merge(df1,df2,all=TRUE), but it wasn't exactly what I've needed.

Comment: How about just `cbind(ID = sum(df1[1], df2[1]), df1[-1], df2[-1])`

Comment: In your desired result, the ID is summed. You need at least one column in both tables to merge on.

Comment: @PierreLapointe: that's why I used names to make the first name of both "ID". Was this wrong?

Comment: As It is a 1-d table, use `c` instead of `cbind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be to `stack`, then `rbind` and do an `aggregate`

```
out <- aggregate(values ~ ., rbind(stack(df1), stack(df2)), sum)
```

To get a named `vector`

```
with(out, setNames(values, ind))
```

---

Or another approach is to concatenate the tables and then use `tapply` to do a group by `sum`

```
v1 <- c(df1, df2)
tapply(v1, names(v1), sum)
```

Or with `rowsum`

```
rowsum(v1, group = names(v1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `rbindlist` from `data.table` and `colSums` to get the totals. `rbindlist` with `fill=TRUE` accepts all columns, even if they are not present in both tables.

```
df1<-read.table(text="ID   a   b   c   d 
241  18  17  28  29 ",header=TRUE)
df2<-read.table(text="ID   e   f   g   h 
230  44   8  37  14" ,header=TRUE)

library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
res <- rbindlist(list(df1,df2), use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
colSums(res, na.rm=TRUE)

 ID   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h 
471  18  17  28  29  44   8  37  14
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the package *[`safejoin`](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin)* that handle this type of tasks in an intuitive way (I hope!). You just need to have a common id between your 2 tables (we'll use `tibble::row_id_to_column` for that) and then you can merge and handle the column conflict with `sum`.

Using @pierre-lapointe's data :

```
library(tibble)
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)

res <- safe_inner_join(rowid_to_column(df1),
                       rowid_to_column(df2),
                       by = "rowid",
                       conflict = sum)

res
#   rowid  ID  a  b  c  d  e f  g  h
# 1     1 471 18 17 28 29 44 8 37 14
```

The for a given row (here the first and only), you can get your pie chart by converting to a vector with unlist and removing the irrelevant 2 first elements :

```
pie(unlist(res[1,])[-(1:2)])
```